# how to set non-database field on a model in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

i want to set / update calculated field on a model, with a different value on each object.

for example, i have a `User` model, and i want to set a `name` property on each user, where `name` is not a column on the DB and it can't be edited by the user.

the names can come from `get_all_users_names()` or from `get_name_by_user_id(id)`.

where should i set it and how should i set it? im new with python so please share some code :) thanks

Comment: `where name is not a column on the DB and it can't be edited by the user` i don't get the point, where should data be stored then? in ram?

Comment: @oruchkin this data come from external api, and i want to present it as if it is a part of the original model + it's to present only, cannot be changed

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Store the `full_name` on the database but not set by a form or on the admin, you can use a `post_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save) to update the field based on the `first_name` and `last_name` fields. You will be able to easily filter and do other DB actions on this column, but you might need to hide the field in a few areas so that it isn't editable.
2. Use a Model method to generate the full name, you can then access this in your views and template - however, you won't be able to do any filtering or other DB actions:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
   ...

   @property
   def full_name(self):
       return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

3. The best option is to annotate your queryset with a full name that [concatenates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) the first_name and last_name field - you can filter the annotation and call it in your templates and views very easily.

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Concat, Value

User.objects.annotate(
   name=Concat('first_name', V(' '), 'last_name'), 
   output_field=CharField())
)
```